# How to get container to grow along with divs?

Tags: javascript, function, dom

Hey guys im trying to build an etch-a-sketch, having issues making my divs stay inside its container. I also would like the container to stretch if I were to add more divs.My divs are made via a function.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script text='text/javascript' src="Etch.js" defer></script>
    <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.squares {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have added height explicitly and this is preventing the container to grow. To fix the issue, update your container css with following code -

```
#container {
  width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: That fixed the gaps thank you so much. Im doing "The Odin Project" and they dont want me using grid just yet. Im trying to make the grid to be 16 x16 but theres spair in the end...thank you again

Comment: Can you mark the answer as done if the issue is fixed?